# Do Australian citizens still get visa-free entry for 360 days in Georgia (the country)?

Tags: visas, georgia-country, caucasus, australian-citizens

Australian citizens definitely used to need a visa to enter the Republic of Georgia a few years back.

Then last year (2010) I entered by land from Turkey and was given a 360-day stamp at the border with no visa necessary.

Now (July 2011) [the Australian Government Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade website](http://www.dfat.gov.au/visas/visas-aabgm.html) says:

> If you are an Australian citizen, you need a visa to visit Armenia, Azerbaijan, Belarus, Georgia and Moldova.

Is this a poorly maintained website or has Georgia really flipflopped on the visa rules for Australian citizens?

Comment: Apparently Georgia is about to change its visa rules in September 2014 to a 90/180 system similar to the systems in use in the Schengen area and in Turkey. I don't think full details are available yet: http://agenda.ge/news/18614/eng

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**End of 2019 update**

The [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Georgia#Visa_policy) says that Georgia adopted a new law that went into effect in 2014 and changed to the 90 out of 180 day system, *but* that **it was amended in June 2015 back to 360 days**.

---

Well until some time in 2014 Australians were still granted 360 day visas on arrival.

However at the last election there was a change of government and the new government eventually changed the visa regime to a "90/180" type where visitors who qualify are now granted permission to stay for ninety days out of any 180 day period. Much like Schengen, Turkey, etc.

Answer (score 5):

[According to this information](http://gruzya.info/info/check_point/visas.php) (this is an up-to-date site), Australia is in the list of countries, citizens of which can stay in Georgia from 90 to 180 days.

This information also is on [the official site of the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Georgia](http://www.mfa.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=96) (as @hippietrail said already):

> **List of the countries whose citizens do not need a visa
>   to enter  and stay on the territory of Georgia for 360 days**
>
> - All countries of the European Union
> - United States of America
> - Canada
> - Japan
> - Switzerland
> - Lichtenstein
> - Norway
> - Israel
> - the Holy See
> - Principality of Andorra
> - San-Marino
> - Republic of Iceland
> - United Arab Emirates
> - State of Kuwait
> - South Korea
> - State of Qatar
> - Kingdom of Bahrain
> - Oman
> - Brunei
> - Singapore
> - ***Australia***
> - Monaco
> - New Zealand
> - Barbados
> - Antigua and Barbuda
> - Trinidad and Tobago
> - Seychelles
> - Botswana
> - Croatia
> - Chile
> - Saint Kitts and Nevis
> - Argentina
> - Malaysia
> - Mexico
> - Uruguay
> - Mauritius
> - Panama
> - Costa Rica
> - South Africa
> - Brazil
> - Thailand
> - Belize
> - Saudi Arabia
> - Republic of Albania
> - Republic of Serbia
> - Bosnia and Herzegovina
> - Montenegro
> - Republic of Iraq

Comment: This changed a few months ago. It's now 90/180. )-: