# How long can a citizen of Iran stay in Georgia (the country) as a tourist?

Tags: visas, georgia-country, us-visa-waiver-program, iranian-citizens, visa-free-entry

I have a friend from Iran here in Tbilisi wondering how long he can stay in the country.

[I know from another question here that as an Australian I can stay for 360 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/do-australian-citizens-still-get-visa-free-entry-for-360-days-in-the-republic-of), but that answer contains a list of which countries get that deal, and it does not include Iran.

This implies from my reading of the rest of [the linked page on the Georgian government's site](http://www.mfa.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=96) that he needs a visa to enter. Yet he assures me he got only a passport stamp at the border when he crossed from Armenia with his Iranian passport.

He even asked at the border how long he could stay and says he was told "as long as you like"!

So are there some different rules for Iranians in Georgia listed somewhere other than on that page? **How long can he stay?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheme for Iranians to visit Georgia visa-free was [cancelled on the 2nd July 2013](http://www.rferl.org/content/georgia-iran-visa-travel/25035168.html). Unless they qualify for [an exemption](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=IR&EM=IR&DE=GE&TR=TR&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), Iranian citizens now need a visa (which can be [obtained online](https://evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/)). This arose from two issues: First, the USA suggesting to Georgia that they should not let Iranians come into the country so easily; and second, Georgia's long-term desire to eventually become an EU member state.

[The exemptions are currently](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=26&lang=Eng):

- 30 days visa-free entry for those born in Georgia but who are not citizens;
- 90 in 180 days for those holding a valid visa or residence permit for a Schengen member state, or for Australia, Bahrain, Bermuda, British Virgin Islands, Canada, Cayman Islands, Falkland Islands, Gibraltar, Israel, Japan, Kuwait, New Zealand, Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, South Korea, Turks and Caicos Islands, USA, or United Arab Emirates. Given the contents of this list, it's quite possible that your Iranian friend already has such a visa.

Comment: That's a bit ironic considering one of the reasons the previous Georgian president lost the election was that he was supposedly some kind of US puppet according to the party that ended up winning in 2012 and then changing this rule. By the way, for Australia and other countries the 360 day visa-free entry rule came back into effect some time in 2015 I believe.

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, [that is still in effect](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=25&lang=Eng).

Comment: Aha I managed not to notice that the list in the 2nd bullet point was for Iranians with visa or residence of those countries and not for the citizens of those countries.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Georgia, Iran visa-free mechanism to take effect on Jan. 26](http://news.xinhuanet.com/english2010/world/2011-01/13/c_13689061.htm)

> The citizens will be able to stay in the country for up to 45 days

Comment: Not true anymore!